# Selected date isn't kept in select box

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have items like this:

```
$scope.items = [{"date":"2014-12-26T05:00:00.000Z","display":"6:00"},
  {"date":"2014-12-26T05:15:00.000Z","display":"6:15"},
  {"date":"2014-12-26T05:30:00.000Z","display":"6:30"}]
```

When I do:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"
  ng-options="{'date':item.date} as item.display for item in items track by item.date"></select>
```

I can select an hour and it stays visible in the select afterwards.  However this is what is being sent to selectedItem:

```
{"date": "2014-12-26T06:15:00.000Z"}
```

If I change it to:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"
  ng-options="item.date as item.display for item in items track by item.date"></select>
```

Then the value

```
"2014-12-26T05:15:00.000Z"
```

is put in selectedItem, which is what I want (because that is what will be posted to the backend as well).  However in the select box it is left blank.  Why is this?

I created a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/qKMPBbQsP6CJAeslrM6E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is because you cannot use *track by* with *select as* syntax. They do not work together.

So just remove track by from the expression, you wouldn't need it with `select as` syntax, just do:

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem"
      ng-options="item.date as item.display for item in items"></select>
```

The above will still result in the ng-model with the `date` property value of the object.

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3crNUMpfIgHU3pExANMf?p=preview)**

**[`Select as` with `track by`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select#-select-as-and-track-by-)**

> With the purpose of preserving the selection, the track by expression is always applied to the element of the data source (to item in this example). To calculate whether an element is selected, we do the following:
>
> 1) Apply track by to the elements in the array. In the example: [1, 2]
>
> 2)Apply track by to the already selected value in ngModel. In the example: this is not possible as track by refers to item.id, but the selected value from ngModel is {name: 'aSubItem'}, **so the track by expression is applied to a wrong object, the selected element can't be found,  is always reset to the "not selected" option.**